Google Sheets SUMIFS with AND and OR arguments
I have a Google Sheet with the following Columns:
B is Item Type
C is Item Source
G is Amount
I'm trying to use the SUMIFS function to add cells from the Amounts column where Item Type is equal to Supplies AND Item Source is either Mixam OR DriveThruRPG.
The syntax I'm trying is:
=SUM(SUMIFS(G:G, B:B, "Supplies", C:C, {"DriveThruRPG","Mixam"})) but it's only displaying the first valid amount in column G when I do this.
I know I can do =SUMIFS(G:G, B:B, "Supplies", C:C, "DriveThruRPG")+SUMIFS(G:G, B:B, "Supplies", C:C,"Mixam") but I'd prefer to keep the formula cleaner, if possible in case I need to add more Item Sources in the future.
Any thoughts?

Use filter() and regexmatch(), like this:
=sum(ifna(filter( 
  G2:G, 
  B2:B = "Supplies", 
  regexmatch(C2:C, "^(DriveThruRPG|Mixam)$") 
)))

See filter() and regexmatch().


You may try:
=sumifs(G:G,B:B,"Supplies",index(xmatch(C:C,{"DriveThruRPG","Mixam"})^0),1)


Do you know if there is a reason why the array I provided wouldn't work?
